# AJAX форма не работает

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

На помощь! Убил 8 часов, результата - 0. Есть код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tt = 0
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime()/1000;
    var s = <?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']; ?>;
    var lefin = (n - s)/60/60;
    if (lefin >= -0.1) {
        var tt = 1
    }
    if (lefin < -0.1) {
        var tt = 2
    }
    if (tt == 1) {
        function ajaxCall(tt) {
            alert("To AJAX: CHECK "+tt);
                jQuery.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "wp-content/plugins/UFR/script.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: "param="+10,
                success: function(response)
                { alert("yoyo")}
            }
        );
};
ajaxCall(tt);
    }
    console.log(n);
    console.log(lefin);
    console.log(tt);
</script>
```

и файл со скриптом:

```
<?php
$timedf = json_decode($_POST['param']);
?>
```

По идеи теперь на моей странице должна стать доступна переменная $timedf - но все тщетно. Кто знает в чем дело, помогите

Comment: На странице будет доступнен `response`. А в php файле я бы сделал `echo json_encode(что-то там);`

Comment: echo json_decode($_POST['param']); не отображается все равно

Comment: data: {"param" : 10},

Comment: @PaulWall, оно и не должно отображаться. Просто потом в `success: function(response) { alert(response); }`

Comment: мне надо переменную из js в php перетащить, может я вообще не то делаю?

Comment: + я это на вп делаю, может я что то не так сделал?

Comment: Неизвестно, что там у вас ещё в коде php. Ваша конструкция может работать, а может и нет. На WordPress так надо делать: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых - ajax в wordpress работает по определенным правилам. Сейчас у вас прямые запросы на файл обработчик, но в вордпресс все ajax запросы должны направляться на `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, а обработчики подключаются к хукам.
Тема ajax в вордпресс достаточно большая, чтобы здесь ее описывать, поэтому изучите [эту статью](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html), чтобы правильно писать рабочий поддерживаемый код.

Если уж хотите, чтобы сейчас работал свой код, попробуйте изменить функцию таким образом:

```
function ajaxCall(tt) {
    alert("To AJAX: CHECK " + tt);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-content/plugins/UFR/script.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          param: 10
        },
        success: function(response) { 
          console.log(response)
        }
    });
}
```

И обращайте внимание на читабельность кода и парность скобок

Comment: Плюсую и поддерживаю.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых проверь, что подключена библиотека JQuery.
Во-вторых в твоём примере, ты организуешь работу веб-приложения с помощью Ajax, это технология асинхронного взаимодействия с сервером, т.е. файл где расположен js скрипт это клиент. Файл script.php это серверный скрипт, по идее там должна быть прописана логика, что делать с данными переданными с клиента.

В твоем примере, ты отсылаешь Ajax запрос в серверный скрипт, скрипт должен что-то там сделать, обработать полученные данные и вернуть результат, который можно будет получить в том месте, где у тебя прописано: alert("yoyo")

```
<?php 

$timedf = json_decode($_POST['param']);
// т.е. клиент ждёт ответ в json, конвертируем ответ в JSON и выводим результат
echo json_encode($timedf);
?>
```

Comment: Суть происходящего ТС понимает, но то ли у него нет инициализации WordPress, потому что делает все неправильно, то ли ещё какая ошибка в коде.

Comment: Это WordPress, там jQuery всегда

Comment: Если вы про date('r'), то это ф-ия вернет текущую дату, вы ошиблись, жаль не могу заминусовать :)

Comment: Ну сморозил, да.. ,